# Restricting the amount of available integers

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to restrict the amount of numbers user can input into the textbox.

For example, I want the `MM/YYYY` format for the expiry date where `MM` does not exceed `12` and includes `01...03` etc. Also the `YYYY` format not exceed `2035`.

Also, I want to restrict the use of numbers (integers) in certain `TextBox`es.

Does anyone know how I would go about that?

Comment: What means "restrict"? What should happpen if the user enters 2036 for example? Have you considered to use a `DateTimePicker` instead?

Comment: I think you'll find something here: [Overview of how to validate user input (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-5.0)

Comment: Try the "MaskedTextBox" control (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wanted to do a DateTimePicker. However, I can't do so as the assignment requires the use of a textbox. Also if the date of 2036 would be inputted then an error would pop up that it's out of its available range.

Comment: You have to just love how assignments stomp best practices just to force students to use something they should learn about instead of coming up with a reasonable assignment.

Comment: @Jcl I will have a look at the MaskedTextBox but I believe that might be the best solution for this problem. Thank you